# Upload file ricefaces fails when text file has leading space

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I have xhtml file that uploads pictures pdf and txt files. code below

```
   <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{DfeOper017MBean.listener}" listWidth="600px"
                         maxFilesQuantity="#{DfeOper017MBean.uploadsAvailable}"
                         id="upload"    
                         styleClass="additionalMarginTop"
                         transferErrorLabel="Wystąpiły problemy. Sprawdź, czy plik został przesłany."
                         noDuplicate="true" immediate="true" ajaxSingle="true"
                         immediateUpload="#{DfeOper017MBean.autoUpload}"
                         allowFlash="#{DfeOper017MBean.useFlash}"
                         acceptedTypes="#{DfeOper017MBean.svAcceptedExtTypes}"
                         addControlLabel="${msg['page.dfeOper017form.fileUpload.addControlLabel']}" 
                         clearAllControlLabel="${msg['page.dfeOper017form.fileUpload.clearAllControlLabel']}"
                         clearControlLabel="${msg['page.dfeOper017form.fileUpload.clearControlLabel']}"
                         stopEntryControlLabel="${msg['page.dfeOper017form.fileUpload.stopEntryControlLabel']}" 
                         uploadControlLabel="${msg['page.dfeOper017form.fileUpload.uploadControlLabel']}"
                         cancelEntryControlLabel="${msg['page.util.abort']}"
                         ontyperejected="alert('The selected file type is not supported.')"
                         doneLabel="${msg['page.util.ok']}" status="waitStatus">
            <f:facet name="label">
                <h:outputText value="{_KB}KB z {KB}KB" />
            </f:facet>
            <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="docsInfoPanel"/>
        </rich:fileUpload>
```

Issue is when i save a file with a space before .txt extention and try to upload  i get the error alert as above ''The selected file type is not supported.', How can i make sure the filename is trimed. ? example of file that fail is "filename .txt", it failes before listner (DfeOper017MBean.listener) is triggered. before it gets to java

I think issue is with rich:fileUpload, but i cant confirm it, any suggestions  ?

Answer (score 3):

The filenames are checked with `/(?:\S+)\.(\S+)$/` so your files won't pass; either rename those files or overwrite the file checking method (`FileUpload.checkFileType`) or upgrade to RF 4.

Comment: But when i try to upload a png or jpeg file, that has a name foto .png it accepts it, only case case is with txt, file .txt, all other extensions dont have a problem with filename having a leading space @Makhiel

Comment: I'm looking at the code for RF 3.3, are you using another version? The only way "foto .png" would be accepted is if `@acceptedTypes` is empty or "*".